# killproc and pidofproc on linux

Tags: linux, shell, process, kill

I have a script which uses killproc and procofpid commands and executes fine on a 64bit suse. But when I executed the script on 32bit redhat , I found that the above commands donot exist.

I don't have a 32bit Suse and 64bit redhat machines to test my script.

Is my guess right that on 64bit redhat the above commands should be available? 
Or are the above commands specific to Suse and redhat?

Thanks

Comment: No, but `kill` and `pidof` are, which are also portable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The commands are unlikely to be portable. Actually this is first time I hear about them - but I guess your problem is to work with process by the name, not pid.

Check the `man pgrep` or `man pkill` - they are slightly bit more portable. They are part of `procps` package (where `ps` and `top` come from) and should be available on all Linux variants. They are also available on Solaris.

Answer (score 9):

killproc is in redhat enterprise linux 5.4 as part of /etc/init.d/functions

if you need it just do

. /etc/init.d/functions

in your script to load the shell functions, its probably in other versions of redhat but thats the only one i have to hand at the moment

Answer (score 6):

These commands are [defined](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html) as part of the [Linux Standards Base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb) (LSB), as noted by @AndreKR.

However, on some systems like Redhat (and probably SUSE), depending on packages installed, these functions may not be defined in the location specified by the LSB, which is `/lib/lsb/init-functions`. Rather they are defined within `/etc/init.d/functions`. In addition, in some versions, the Redhat variant of `/etc/init.d/functions` is missing the LSB-defined function `start_daemon`. If you add the following snippet to the top of your script, it should be portable across most distributions/installs:

```
if [[ -f /lib/lsb/init-functions ]]; then
  . /lib/lsb/init-functions
elif [[ -f /etc/init.d/functions ]]; then
  . /etc/init.d/functions
  # Pretend to be LSB-compliant
  function start_daemon() {
    daemon $*
  }
else
  echo "Linux LSB init function script or Redhat /etc/init.d/functions is required for this script."
  echo "See http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Your statement `Redhat (and probably SUSE) does not define them in the location specified by the LSB` is false. The meta package `lsb-core-noarch` provides the file `/lib/lsb/init-functions` across LSB compliant distributions. Just use the the distribution package manager to install.

Comment: @Samveen Thank you for the clarification and information about the `lsb-core-noarch` package. FWIW, on Fedora 24, it is `redhat-lsb-core`. The script snippet is still useful if you're not sure whether runtime environments have the package installed or not, and you have no capability or desire to force its installation.

Comment: Please check the `provides` for the `redhat-lsb-core` package: You'll notice that it `provides` a capability `lsb-core-noarch` which is a `meta package`, as I mentioned in my comment ([rpmfind info](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/updates/24/x86_64/r/redhat-lsb-core-4.1-33.fc24.x86_64.html)).

Comment: @Samveen Your link to `rpmfind` is an external site that appears to have out of date information. See here: https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/redhat-lsb-core/overview/. `redhat-lsb-core` is actually a subpackage of the meta package `redhat-lsb`, and it "Provides" `lsb-noarch`, which isn't a package but a capability.

Comment: I don't see any section on that page that lists information about the `Provides:` section of the package, so I'll link to the spec file at http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/redhat-lsb.git/tree/redhat-lsb.spec : please note the `Provides:` under `%package core`. 
All in all, you're missing my point: `start_daemon` is provided on Fedore (or any LSB compliant distribution), just need to install the distribution independent  capability `lsb-core-noarch`, using the distribution's inbuilt package manager. eg. `yum install lsb-core-noarch` or `apt-get install lsb-core-noarch`

Comment: @Samveen No, I'm not missing the point, I got that point from your first comment.

Answer (score 2):

The ones used in Ubuntu are part of the specification "[Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base)" and are documented [there](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_4.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/iniscrptfunc.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think those commands are distrib specifics: I have never seen them before.
killproc should be a kind of kill but what is procofpid supposed to do?

In the title you speak about pidofproc, you can find this command under the pidof on most linux boxes.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you, it gave the warning:

> pidof: invalid options on command line!

I changed the

```
"killproc -d 10 $cmd"
```

to

```
"kill -9 \`pidof $cmd\`"
```